# Socket.Io how to emit to all members in a room from a socket instance including the sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sockets, socket.io

How do I emit to all members of a room from a socket instance?

I know I can do `io.in('room').emit('event', data);` if I have access to the IO instance, but in my case I only have access to the socket of the sender, I store the socket of the user in a user object, and pass it around my code so that I can emit from anywhere, but as a result I have no access to the IO instance.

How can I emit to all members of a room including the sender from the sender's socket instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is best to give yourself access to the `io` instance in some way so you can do `io.in(room).emit(...)`.  You can either export it from where you create it and then import it where you are or you can make it available some other way.

Here are four other ways to do it:

**Attach `.io` property to each socket**

In the file, where you create the `io` instance, you can attach it as a property to every socket.

```
// put io on each socket
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.io = io;
});
```

Then, on any socket, you can get `io` with `socket.io`.

---

**Put `io` instance in your `app` object**

If `app` is available, then some folks put the `io` instance on the `app` object with `app.set("io", io);` so code elsewhere can get it with `io.get("io");`.

---

**Send to both room and self**

As a work-around, you could also just send to both:

```
socket.broadcast(room).emit(...);
socket.emit(...);
```

---

**Use undocumented `socket.server`**

There is also an undocumented property on the `socket` which gives you access to the server object.  Use at your own risk:

```
socket.server.in("room").emit(...);
```

which essentially gives you the `io` instance.